# Hadoop Administrator Questions

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Can someone help me when to use and purpose of the below command in hadoop

```
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode wait
```

In Production level what is the role majorly it play? 
As per my understandings we can pass `hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave` 
and `hdfs dfsadmin -safemode enter` rather than using the `wait` command. Let me know if my understandings are right.

Answer (score 1):

```
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode wait
```

is to wait until the HDFS finishes data block replication and is ready for operation.

In cases where you would want the namenode to exit `safemode` before executing a command, this `wait` option can be used.

Consider an example script containing these lines,

```
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode wait
hdfs dfs -mkdir /test
```

Here, the `mkdir` will not be executed until the namenode has exited `safemode`. This is guaranteed by the `wait`.

Safemode `leave` and `enter` are to turn safemode `OFF` and `ON`, and are used to enter/exit safemode manually when carrying out maintenances to make the FS readonly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I accept
Basically I want to understand for what it is used. And I got answers with your response.thank you